# Program cannot Sort

Tags: python, oop

new to python , trying to learn oops ,
in below code my objective is to sort employee list based on rating but stuck at object not iteratable.

```
class Employee:
    def getfn(self):
        self.empid=(input(" enter emp id:"))
        self.name=input("enter name:")
        self.gender=input("enter emp gender: ")
        self.salary=input(" enter emp salary:")
        self.rating=int(input("enter rating:"))

empz=[]
class menu:
    n=0
    def entry(self):
        n=int(input(" enter no of employees:"))
        i=0
        while i<n:
            temp_emp=Employee()
            temp_emp.getfn()
            empz.append(temp_emp)
            i+=1
    def print_rec(self):
         #
         print("-id--name--gender--salary--rating--")
         for i in empz:
             print(i.empid,i.name,i.gender,i.salary,i.rating)
         #print(sorted(empz,key=lambda x:x[4]))

def sort_rating(empz):
    return empz.rating

sorted_emp=sorted(empz, key= sort_rating)
print(empz)
```

Comment: Your program never asks for any input so the *empz* list will always be empty. Also, don't try getting input within your Employee class. Rather do it outside of the class (so you can validate) then pass relevant values to the class constructor (which you haven't yet defined)

Answer (score 1):

The design of your Employee class isn't great. Values used as its attributes should be validated before class construction.

You can control the number of employees to be input more easily than asking for a count.

Hopefully this will give a better idea of how this might be done.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, empid, name, gender, salary, rating):
        self.empid = empid
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.salary = salary
        self.rating = rating
    def __str__(self):
        return f'ID={self.empid}, Name={self.name}, Gender={self.gender}, Salary={self.salary}, Rating={self.rating}'

# common input functions
def getInput(prompt, t=str):
    while True:
        v = input(f'{prompt}: ')
        try:
            return t(v)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input')

def getInt(prompt):
    return getInput(prompt, int)

def getFloat(prompt):
    return getInput(prompt, float)
# end of common input functions

employeeList = []

while eid := getInput('ID (Enter to finish)'):
    name = getInput('Name')
    gender = getInput('Gender')
    salary = getFloat('Salary')
    rating = getInt('Rating')
    employeeList.append(Employee(eid, name, gender, salary, rating))

for employee in sorted(employeeList, key=lambda x: x.rating):
    print(employee)
```

The common input functions should be in a separate py file so you can import them when needed rather than re-writing them every time. They're trivial but you'll find them helpful when trying to ensure that input is appropriate